# maintain single useState for all column values in a table row using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a react-bootstrap table which has 4 column values.
i am looking for a way using react hooks useState where - I can maintain state of all the column values in the same state object and whenever the state of any of the column values changes the entire row is updated.

I am very new to reactjs and react hooks, please do let me know if this can be done using any other react hook.
thanks!

In the below code..i have 2 useState..one to update state when the textarea is changed , other one to update the dropdown selected value.
I want to know if i can maintain single useState and everytime there is a change in any of the table columns i will trigger a single callback function and update state using single useState.
I also am not sure if the state will be replaced or the previous state(of all rows in the table) will be retained

```
<div>
<Table striped bordered hover>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>Text</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Data Property</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{data.map((item,index) => (
<tr key={index}>
<td>{item.id}</td>
<td>{item.color}</td>
<td>
<div className="userInput">
<InputGroup>
<Form.Control as="textarea" aria-label="With textarea" rows={1} value={newTitle.labelTitle} onChange={(e) => handleTitleChange(e)}/>
</InputGroup>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1">
<Form.Control as="select">
{dropDownData.map((data,index) => (
<option key={index} onChange = {(e)=>handleDataPropertyChange(e)}>{data}</option>
))}
</Form.Control>
</Form.Group>
</td>
</tr>
))}
</tbody>
</Table>
</div>

const [newTitle, setTitle] = useState(data);
    const [newDataProperty, setDataProperty] = useState(dropDownData);

    const handleTitleChange = (e) => {
        setTitle(e.target.value);   
    }

    const handleDataPropertyChange = (e) => {
        setDataProperty(e.target.textContent);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your object structure that you need to store in the state?

Comment: show your code, what you have achieved so far?

Comment: could someone pls help me